# Having trouble accessing information from an object to pass as a prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, react-props

I am trying to pass information into my film details prop (specfically the title of the film) this is the object (commented out in my code for reference but it's actually part of a different file I am getting no import errors in):

---file TMDB.js ---

```
`// const TMDB = {
//   api_key: 'f------',
//   films: [
//     {
//       "id": 346364,
//         "title": "It",
//         "poster_path": "/9E2y5Q7WlCVNEhP5GiVTjhEhx1o.jpg",
//         "backdrop_path": "/tcheoA2nPATCm2vvXw2hVQoaEFD.jpg",
//         "overview": "In a small town in Maine, seven children known as The Losers Club come face to face with life problems, bullies and a monster that takes the shape of a clown called Pennywise.",`
```

at the end of the file, I wrote an export default expression

This is the error I am getting:

```
    "TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined"
```

This is the file I am trying to get the title of the object to display in - what am I missing ?:

---file FilmListing.js

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import FilmDetails from './../FilmDetails/FilmDetails.js'
import { TMDB } from '../../TMDB.js'

class FilmListing extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
render() {
    return(
      <div className="film-list">
          <h1 className="section-title">FILMS</h1>
          <p> <FilmDetails/> </p>
          <p film = {TMDB.props.title}> {this.film.title} </p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

edit- I've tried `{this.props.films}`
                 `{this.props.TMDB.title}`
                 `{this.props.TMDB.films.title}`

I assume I have to access the title as part of an array or something (there are multiple other entries, I am just trying to display one object)

Comment: *This is the file I am trying to get the title of the object to display in - what am I missing ?* - you're missing the code where TMDB prop is passed. The problem is there.

Comment: How do i pass it as a prop ? I assume this.props.TMDB.title isn't it then ? , or this.props.title ?

Comment: How do you use this component? Why do you expect TMDB/title to be there? The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and is offtopic in its current state.

Comment: I guess i don't understand how it is still coming back as undefined.when it is defined as a const in a seperate JS file i imported.

Comment: There's no `props` property in `TMDB` object. And there's no `title` as well. There's `film` and it's an array. Is your intention to get `TMDB.films[0].title`? You need to iterate `films` array, but your code doesn't show the intention to output multiple film entries, so it's unclear what you're trying to achieve. I guess the problem isn't specific to React and you need to figure out how to work with objects in JS.

Comment: thanks, estus, I went over js before but I am also pretty forgetful. I will go back and so some review. I just needed a hint and that's perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized I had to go back and look at the structure of the object to learn how I was supposed to properly call it.

My app now renders like this (grabbing all the film titles instead of one)

```
render() {
    return(
      <div className="film-list">
          <h1 className="section-title">FILMS</h1>
          <p> <FilmDetails/> </p>
          <p> {TMDB.films.map((film , index)=> {
            return (
          <div>
            <h2>
              {film.release_date}
            </h2>
            <p>
              {film.title} <br/>
              {film.id}
            </p>
          </div>
           )
          })
          } </p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```